# Finding the selected item of list view

Tags: c#, listview, contextmenustrip

I currently have a list view which has several rows of data and I have a contextmenustrip in C# .NET.

What I am having problems with is when you click on the menu strip item I want to know which row has been selected.

Comment: Any chance of some sample code/simple example - it sounds pretty straightforward

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get selected rows as sindre says you do like this:

```
foreach (ListViewItem item in lvFiles.SelectedItems)
{
....................................
}
```

lvFiles is the ListView.

Answer (score 1):

To get the selected item of list view, try this:

int index = 0; 
if (this.myListView.SelectedItem.Count > 0) 
index = this.myListView.SelectedIndices[0]

This will give you the index of selected item in listview.
You may also refer this:

http://www.neowin.net/forum/index.php?showtopic=358458

Answer (score 0):

I really don't know what you mean here.  Can you please explain your problem further or provide a code example?

To get the selected row in a ListView you use the ListView.SelectedItems property.  ListView.SelectedItems[0] will give you the first seleted item (as there can be more than one item selected)