# Finding selected item of Ultralistview

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview, infragistics

What is alternative to ListView's SelectedIndices property in Infragistics UltraListview?

FYI: SelectedIndices Property gets index of Selected Item in List View.

For more info please refer: [Finding the selected item of list view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/325241/finding-the-selected-item-of-list-view)

Please reply

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UltraListView.SelectedItems` returns a collection of `UltraListViewItem` objects with `Selected = True`.

To emulate the SelectedIndicies, you can call this LINQ code (VB):

```
Dim indicies() as Integer = CType(listView.SelectedItems.All(), UltraListViewItem()).Select(Function(i) i.Index).ToArray()
```